Microsoft Fabric - Upsert Only ETL (Ignore Deletes)
I am exploring Fabric as a data warehouse solution. For the first step, I want to copy source tables in from an application database. For certain tables I would like an ETL that does not delete, only inserts or updates.
The reason I am doing this, is some records will be purged from the application DB but I would like them to be available in the source copies in Synapse.
Is this possible with Fabric or Azure Data Factory using the WYSISWG editor?

In Fabric, writing to a table in a lakehouse using data factory, you have the following options:

Append - only append rows
Overwrite - overwrite the entire table


If you need to update existing rows, the best approach would be to write the data to a staging table (using overwrite) and then use a notebook with either SQL or Python code to merge the records to the destination table.
Lets say your stg table is called stg_orders and the destination table is called orders:
%%sql
merge into orders o
using stg_orders s
on o.orderid = s.orderid
when MATCHED then update set *
when not MATCHED by target then insert *

This command compares the tables by the columns in the "on" clause.
If there is a match it will update all fields (that is what the * means).  If there is no match, that means that this key is missing in the destination table and the merge command will insert it. No rows are deleted in this example.

This appears to just append the full table to the end of the existing rows. Am I missing a setting that it only retrieves new rows?
I am looking to stay very low code.

@Daniel , my apologies, you are quite right and I fixed my answer. I think you will have to use some code to merge your rows by key (insert for new, update for existing). Please check out the "merge" command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/merge

@Daniel I added the required code example to the post
